# Get Office 365 Mailboxes and Groups from Python

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, office365api, azure-sdk-python, exchangelib

A coworker made a working PowerShell script to retrieve Mailboxes and Groups from Office 365.
We have both admin rights on Office 365 = I can get all of these information with a internet browser on EAC. When I'm executing the PowerShell script with my Office 365 credentials, I get the excepted results. It means that I have the rights access and permissions on Exchange.

My need is to create a Python script to do almost the same thing then to create a human-readable Excel Workbook (probably using openpyxl) and send email later. Many of you will ask to me why I don't complete the PowerShell script, the simple answer is that this script will be a little part of a biggest project, written in Python.

Here, the PowerShell script:

```
Install-Module -Name AzureAD
Install-Module -Name MSOnline

$CSV_Groups = "C:\tmp\Groups.csv"

#Get Credentials to connect
$Credential = Get-Credential

#Create the session
$Session = New-PSSession -ConfigurationName Microsoft.Exchange -ConnectionUri https://outlook.office365.com/powershell-liveid/ -Credential $Credential -Authentication Basic -AllowRedirection

#Import the session
Import-PSSession $Session -DisableNameChecking

$O365Groups = Get-UnifiedGroup
ForEach ($Group in $O365Groups) {
    Get-UnifiedGroupLinks –Identity $Group.Id –LinkType Members | Select-Object @{Name="Group Name";Expression={$Group.DisplayName}}, @{Name="Group Address";Expression={$Group.PrimarySmtpAddress}}, @{Name="User Name";Expression={$_.DisplayName}}, PrimarySmtpAddress | Export-CSV $CSV_Groups -NoTypeInformation -Append -encoding UTF8
}

$O365Groups = Get-DistributionGroup
ForEach ($Group in $O365Groups) {
    Get-DistributionGroupMember –Identity $Group.Id | Select-Object @{Name="Group Name";Expression={$Group.DisplayName}}, @{Name="Group Address";Expression={$Group.PrimarySmtpAddress}}, @{Name="User Name";Expression={$_.DisplayName}}, PrimarySmtpAddress | Export-CSV $CSV_Groups -NoTypeInformation -Append -encoding UTF8
}

$CSV_Mailboxes = "C:\tmp\Mailboxes.csv"
Get-Mailbox -RecipientTypeDetails SharedMailbox -ResultSize:Unlimited | Get-MailboxPermission | Select-Object Identity,User,AccessRights | Export-Csv $CSV_Mailboxes -NoTypeInformation
Remove-PSSession $Session
```

I don't want an application to have access to Azure AD. The same way the Powershell script ask for user Credentials, I would like my python script to prompt for Office 365 credentials. I would like my python script to work this way to be sure only office 365 users with right rights can use this python script.

I have tested 4 python libraries, for all of them, I succeed the authentication but I don't find the right way to list all groups and mailboxes

Using ExchangeLib (https://github.com/ecederstrand/exchangelib):

```
import exchangelib

exchangelib_credentials = exchangelib.Credentials(
    username=self.username,
    password=self.password
)
exchangelib_account = exchangelib.Account(
    primary_smtp_address="my_email@address.com",
    credentials=exchangelib_credentials,
    autodiscover=True
)
for mailbox in account.protocol.get_searchable_mailboxes(expand_group_membership=True):
    print(mailbox)
# ==> exchangelib.errors.ErrorAccessDenied:
# The caller has not assigned any of the RBAC roles requested in the management role header.
```

I'm certainly not using this library correctly because I don't get why I need more permissions than the ones I already have?
I've followed this page, but I've got the same error:
https://documentation.arcserve.com/Arcserve-UDP/Available/V6.5/ENU/Bookshelf_Files/HTML/Solutions%20Guide/UDPSolnGuide/udp_add_role_group_exchgonline.htm

I tried Azure SDK for Python (https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python), O365 (https://github.com/O365/python-o365) and Office365-REST-Python-Client (https://github.com/vgrem/Office365-REST-Python-Client).
I succeed to (seems to) authenticate with all of them, but failed to list all mailboxes or groups.

Anyone could help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about the Exchange Graph API, but EWS simply does not provide this information. Your best bet is the [GetSearchableMailboxes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/exchange/client-developer/web-service-reference/getsearchablemailboxes-operation) service that you tried in exchangelib. EWS requires users to have the Discovery Management RBAC role for this to succeed.

Since you already have PowerShell commands that work for you, I would probably just call these commands from your Python script using a subprocess. Here's a blog post with some examples: https://www.phillipsj.net/posts/executing-powershell-from-python/

Comment: Hello Erik and thank you for your reply. I wished to be cross platform, but if I don't have the choice, I'll use subprocesses.